# Unitary Representations of $SL(5,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Has there been a complete classification of unitary representations of $SL(5,\mathbb{R})$? If so, could someone please direct me to a reference which details it? I am having a hard time finding any results.

Comment: You meant to infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces ie. including (cuspidal) automorphic forms ?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for infinite dimensional representations.